# Firebase Function Unable to find a valid endpoint for function app

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I have a firebase functions folder which I am trying to connect to my frontend app to run calls to my backend server.

The function folder got set up and worked with the emulator, when I tried to use these function in the front end app however they didn't work. The following error showed: Error: Unable to find a valid endpoint for function app

This is what I added to the frontend firebaase.json file:

```
"hosting": {

    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/bigben",
        "function": "bigben",
        "region": "us-central1"
      },
      {
        "source": "/create-customer-portal-session",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then this is the index.js file in the functions folder:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
app.use(cors);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const hours = (new Date().getHours() % 12) + 1  // London is UTC + 1hr;
  res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${'BONG '.repeat(hours)}
    </body>
  </html>`);
});

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

const priceId = 'price_1LaJC1CKMdmWgnyspBbFet9v';

const storeItems = new Map([
    [
    1, { priceInCents: 10000, name: 'Item 1 Name'}
    ],
    [
    2, { priceInCents: 20000, name: 'Item 2 Name'}
    ],
])

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const cust = req.body.customerId
  const price = req.body.priceId
  const quantity = req.body.students
  const quantityA = Number(quantity)

    try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        mode: 'subscription',
        allow_promotion_codes: true,
      customer: cust,  
        line_items: [
          {
            price: price,
            // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
            quantity: quantityA,
          },
        ],
        success_url: `https://learning-platform.web.app/`,
        cancel_url: `https://learning-platform.web.app/`,
      }) 
      res.redirect(session.url);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
    } 
  })


  app.post('/create-customer-portal-session', async (req, res) => {
    const cust = req.body.customerId
    // Authenticate your user.
    const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
      customer: cust,
    
    });
  console.log(session.url)
   res.redirect(session.url);
  });
```

This is what is returned when I run the command: firebase deploy --only functions,hosting --debug

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share what URL are you trying to access from your client side ?

Comment: I'm trying to access the stripe checkout URLs. Stripe.checkout.sessions.create makes a unique session URL for the user. This works great when I run the server locally. I am trying to deploy this backend server through a firebase function so that it works for everyone, and not just when the server runs locally on my computer.

Comment: Still returns -  Error: Unable to find a valid endpoint for function app.    Exports.bigben is the function from the firebase documentation. The frontend allowed me to deploy firebase hosting when it was just this bigben function, however when I visited the URL /bigben nothing showed up. Could it be that I am not using the export correctly?

Comment: Can you move the `"source": "**",` rewrite to the end of array? Also can you share a screenshot of the error that might contain some more error logs?

Comment: I've moved source to the end of the array, still return the same error. The error happens when I run  firebase deploy --only functions,hosting in the terminal so I don't know if there are any additional logs to share?

Comment: Try running the same with `--debug` flag once?

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of what returns when it is run with --debug